# Selenium ChromeDriver not finding elements, while firefox driver can find same elements (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been going through the process of learning selenium. I wrote a script using the firefox webdriver that works well. However I am now trying to convert that script to work with headless chrome.

What I wrote:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.snl.com/web/client?auth=inherit&contextType=external&username=string&enablePersistentLogin=true&OverrideRetryLimit=0&SwitchGetToPostLimit=50000&contextValue=%2Foam&password=secure_string&challenge_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.snl.com%2Fweb%2Fclient%3Fauth%3Dinherit&request_id=-2343654539289081584&authn_try_count=0&locale=en_GB&resource_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.snl.com%252Finteractivex%252Fdefault.aspx')
time.sleep(14)
login_forms = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('form-control.input-sm.snl-widgets-input-text.snl-selectable.action')
username = login_forms[3]
password = login_forms[4]
username.send_keys('user')
password.send_keys('pass')
```

I am aware that using time.sleep is not optimal and there are better ways to achieve my wait in selenium. I am going to go back and correct that later.
That said the above code works on [snl.com](https://platform.mi.spglobal.com/web/client?auth=inherit&contextType=external&username=string&enablePersistentLogin=true&OverrideRetryLimit=0&SwitchGetToPostLimit=50000&contextValue=%2Foam&password=secure_string&challenge_url=https%3A%2F%2Fplatform.mi.spglobal.com%2Fweb%2Fclient%3Fauth%3Dinherit&request_id=4311707420879188793&authn_try_count=0&locale=en_GB&resource_url=https%253A%252F%252Fplatform.mi.spglobal.com%252Finteractivex%252Fdefault.aspx) when my webdriver is firefox, but not at all when it is chrome.

I have tried debugging by printing the innerhtml, but chrome returns nothing.

Hoping that somebody out there might have some insight as to what is going wrong here.
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the `Email address` and `Password` fields the `Locator Strategy` which you have used looks brittle. You have to adopt a `Locator Strategy` which uniquely identifies the `Email address` and `Password` field through any of the following code blocks :

- **`css_selector`** :

  ```
  username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control.input-sm.snl-widgets-input-text.snl-selectable.action[name=username]")
  password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control.input-sm.snl-widgets-input-text.snl-selectable.action[name=password]")
  username.send_keys('user')
  password.send_keys('pass')
  ```
- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control input-sm snl-widgets-input-text snl-selectable action' and @name='username']")
  password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control input-sm snl-widgets-input-text snl-selectable action' and @name='password']")
  username.send_keys('user')
  password.send_keys('pass')
  ```